# Protect some pages from direct access

Tags: php, modx

I'm trying to password protect some pages from the public. To login I have to use an external page located in an iframe and create this login on their website with a callback address which should be to the protected pages.

The only thing I get back if a login is successful is a GET method to the page I want that just has dc=1 if correct and a timestamp.

So if I would use a php script as the callback address then just adding ?dc=1 to the end would give you access to the page.

I thought I could use the session id from when the startpage is loaded but then they just need to load the start page once and then the call back address to get access.

Does anyone know a secure way to restrict access to some pages using this type of external login as I've described?

Comment: It sounds like the "external login" isn't very secure. Perhaps you should find a different provider of authentication.

Comment: Problem is that its not my decision. So I want to do the best with what I have!

Comment: MODX Evo or Revo? Is the 'login page' a MODX page, and the 'protected page' on some other system? Are both sites located on the same server?

Comment: Using revolution. The starting page and the protected pages are all in revolution and on the same server. Only the login is located on a different one.

Answer (score -1):

set .htacesss to deny from everything but your IP ?

Comment: Wouldn't that block pretty much everyone except myself? Its suppose to work from any computer.